# Mock class with fluent interface in Phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am mocking this sample class with fluent methods that doesn't have return type declaration:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    private string $x;
    private string $y;
    
    public function setX(string $x)
    {
        $this->x = $x;
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function setY(string $y)
    {
        $this->y = $y;
        return $this;
    }   
}
```

Using PhpUnit:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Foo::class)
    ->getMock();
```

By default, this will not work on fluent methods without return type declaration so I need to add the ff.:

```
$mock->method('setX')->will($this->returnSelf());
$mock->method('setY')->will($this->returnSelf());
```

This works but cumbersome to write if there are a lot fluent methods. My question is, is there a way to set this for the entire class instead of per method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this. This would afford a way to the mock to return itself for a certain set of methods and phpunit mocks do not have such functionality.

If you need this for a lot of methods you could create a manual mock (just a simple class that extends the class-to-mock and implement the magic method `__call()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).